# Issue with Join for mySQL - is it possible to do what I want?

Tags: mysql, join

- tableA columns: homeid,awayid,date
- tableB columns: id, logo,schoolname

tableB ID matches the IDs in tableA

Maybe this won't work but I have to think it's better then looping in PHP.

I want results like this for a specific date:

```
hometeamname hometeamlogo awayteamname awayteamlogo
```

all in one line

Is that possible?

Comment: Short answer is *yes*, it's possible. The queries in some answers do return the specified resultset, but the queries some of the answers do not.

Answer (score 1):

Do two joins to get the home and away data.

```
select b1.schoolname hometeamname, b1.logo hometeamlogo,
       b2.schoolname awayteamname, b2.logo awayteamlogo
from tableA a
join tableB b1 on b1.id = a.homeid
join tableB b2 on b2.id = a.awayid
where a.date = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

Comment: +1. This is how I would do it, though I would have likely used different table aliases (**m** for meet/match/game, **a** for away team, and **h** for hometeam), and I would also qualify the `date` column in the WHERE clause (so a reader isn't left to wonder which table that column is retrieved from.) Otherwise, identical to the answer I would have given.

Comment: @spencer7593 Well, in the real application, the tables wouldn't be named `tableA` and `tableB`, either. I chose aliases related to the table names, not the semantics, but I see your point.

Comment: And make sure you have a index on a.homeid and a.awayid and date or this query will be very slow.. (more like information for topic starter..)

Comment: Right. I basically ignored the (unfortunate) names of `tableA` and `tableB`, and made the leap to what I thought the actual table names might be. tableB really represents a "team", but in the "away" or "home" roles in each (tableA) "meet".

Comment: @Raymond: actually, for optimum performance, the most appropriate index on tableA would have a leading column of `date`. Including the `homeid` and `awayid` columns in that index would make it a "covering"  index. And the `id` column on tableB is likely the primary key (we don't know that, we're just making a guess), and that's likely going to give adequate performance.

Comment: @RaymondN Right. Indexes on `homeid` and `awayid` might be useful for other queries (e.g. on what dates did team X play?), but they're not needed for this join.

Comment: @spencer7593 if you mean a key like this KEY(date, homeid, awayid) then "join tableB b2 on b2.id = a.awayid" looks like it can't use an index then. I can't say for sure  i always check the output off EXPLAIN to make sure

Comment: @RaymondN He's saying that the important indexes for this query are `KEY(tableA.date)` and `KEY(tableB.id)`. The latter is probably tableB's primary key. This is such a simple query, it would be extremely surprising if these two keys didn't give as optimal a search as possible -- one lookup to get the table A rows by date, then find the two matching table B rows for each of them.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed i see i mis understood him then thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can join `tableB` twice, using two different aliases `h` and `a`:

```
SELECT
  h.schoolname hometeamname,
  h.logo hometeamlogo,
  a.schoolname awayteamname,
  a.logo awayteamlogo
FROM
  tableA inner join tableB h on tableA.homeid=h.id
  inner join tableB a on tableA.awayid=a.id
```

then you can filter by date.

Answer (score 0):

On table A the tableB id's are multivalued?

if yes;

```
select * from tablea
inner join tableb on tableb.id IN(tablea.awayid)
```

if no

```
select * from tablea
inner join tableb on tableb.id = tablea.awayid
```

i don't have pretty sure about what you want

Answer (score 0):

Do join, something like (did not check it so may have syntax errros):

```
select H.schoolname as hometeamname, H.logo as hometeamlogo, 
       W.schoolanme as awayteamname, W.logo as awayteamlogo 
       from tableA as A join tableB as H on (tableA.homeid = H.id) 
       join table B as W on (tableA.homeid = W.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

```
SELECT home.schoolname, home.logo, away.schoolname, away.logo
FROM tableB home, tableB away
WHERE (home.id, away.id) IN (SELECT homeid, awayid FROM tableA)
```

Comment: This is slow and should be rewriten like a JOIN like Barmar answer. MySQL optimizer can't fix this subquery... and should be AVOIDED..

Comment: @RaymondN Thanks for your input. I know it works but I haven't tested the performance of the query. Learned something new..thanks.